# WP order post by publish date

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have been trying for days to sort the posts that will be shown in the homepage of a template in Wordpress based on their publication date.
In particular I have tried to sort the array that contains the post_id with different functions (array_multisort, ksort, usort etc.) but without getting to the mentioned purpose.
Could you help me overcome that difficulty?
Here is the code of the template parts:

```
<?php
$date_publish = new DateTime($post->post_date);
$manual_articles = dsi_get_option("manual_articles", "homepage");
if(is_array($manual_articles) && count($manual_articles)){
?>

    <section class="section bg-white py-2 py-lg-3 py-xl-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title-section pb-4">
            <h2 class="h2"><?php _e("News"); ?></h2>
        </div><!-- /title-section -->
        <div class="row variable-gutters">
                <?php
                foreach ( $manual_articles as $idpost ) {
                    if(++$i > 3) break; // 3 post max
                    $post = get_post($idpost); 
//                  echo strtotime($post->post_date);
                    if($post->post_type != "event") {
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
                            <?php
                                get_template_part("template-parts/single/card-vertical-thumb", $post->post_type);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Thank you..

Sort an array with a different function with no result

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to sort the **$manual_articles** array based on the publication date of each post. You can achieve this using the **usort()** function, which sorts an array using a custom comparison function. Here's some changes, i have change in your code that sorts the posts based on their publication date:

```
<?php
$manual_articles = dsi_get_option("manual_articles", "homepage");
if (is_array($manual_articles) && count($manual_articles)) {
    // Define a custom comparison function for sorting based on publication date
    function compare_posts_by_date($a, $b) {
        $post_a = get_post($a);
        $post_b = get_post($b);
        $date_a = strtotime($post_a->post_date);
        $date_b = strtotime($post_b->post_date);

        return $date_b - $date_a; // Sort in descending order (latest first)
    }

    // Sort the array using the custom comparison function
    usort($manual_articles, "compare_posts_by_date");
?>

<section class="section bg-white py-2 py-lg-3 py-xl-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title-section pb-4">
            <h2 class="h2"><?php _e("News"); ?></h2>
        </div><!-- /title-section -->
        <div class="row variable-gutters">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($manual_articles as $idpost) {
                if (++$i > 3) break; // 3 post max
                $post = get_post($idpost);
                if ($post->post_type != "event") {
            ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 mb-4">
                        <?php
                        get_template_part("template-parts/single/card-vertical-thumb", $post->post_type);
                        ?>
                    </div>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php
} // Close the if statement
?>
```

With this modification, the **$manual_articles** array will be sorted by publication date in descending order (latest first) before displaying the posts on the homepage.